# How can I check if text content on page changed?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I want to check if the text content in the var cart changes its on this page: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all

```
let cart = document.getElementById('items-count').textContent;

console.log(cart);
cart.addEventListener('change', function() {
 console.log("cart");
 window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: cart.addEventListener is not a function
> at chrome-extension://ljhadajgdcijdfoopfbkjibfebkilieh/supreme.js:11:6

The script starts when I enter the page.

I already tried to Monitor it with a while loop like in the following code but then the website freezes and I cant use it anymore until the var change

```
let carted = 0
let cart = document.getElementById('items-count').textContent;
while (carted < 1 ) {
console.log(cart);
if (cart.length > 2) {
    cart ++;
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to add an event listener to your element's `textContent`, not to your element, and you can't do that. Just do this

```js
let cart = document.getElementById('items-count');

console.log(cart);
cart.addEventListener('change', function() {
 console.log(`cart content has changed — ${cart.textContent}`);
 window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

Comment: it didnt detect this change https://prnt.sc/j2SSE0rgK9kB

Comment: I'm sure it's not `change` but `onchange`. Refer to MDN for the list of event listeners, you might find something you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a listener, you can't do it to `textContent`.

```js
let cart = document.getElementById('items-count'); //.textContent

console.log(cart);
cart.addEventListener('change', function() {
 console.log("cart");
 window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

If you need that value, you can store it on another variable:

```
var content = cart.textContent
```

Comment: yes but when i use it like this it didnt detects the change do you have an idea how i can detect the change in the text content i need to detect this change https://prnt.sc/j2SSE0rgK9kB

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
var item = document.getElementById('items-count');
item.addEventListener("change", DoStuff);
function DoStuff(){
//do what do you want to do.
}
```

Comment: when i use it like this it didnt detects the change do you have an idea how i can detect the change in the text content: https://prnt.sc/j2SSE0rgK9kB

Comment: how to change this text? if change it by AJAX you could use there